# Printing Average of Positive Numbers

Tags: php, average

How can I do this exercise using php? 
Write a program that requests the user to type positive numbers, or to stop by typing a number smaller than 1. Print the average.Use do-while loop.

```
Enter Number : 3
Enter Number : 5
Enter Number : 11
Enter Number : 1
Enter Number : 0
Average : 5


Enter Number : 31
Enter Number : 4
Enter Number : 4
Enter Number : -12
Average : 13
```

I tried to finish it like this.

```
do {
echo 'Enter a number: ';
$number = trim(fgets(STDIN));
if($number < 1) {
    break;
}
$sum += $number;
++$count;
} while(true);


$avg = $sum / max($count,1);

//}
echo("Average : ".$avg);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: This seems like the kind of thing PHP really isn't designed for. What's the purpose of this excercise?

Comment: Start the code with `<?php`, seems to work for me...

Comment: What is the problem exactly ? Aside from the fact that notices are raised since you use variable without initializing them, your code does the job for me...

Comment: Guess he needs to check for incorrect input too.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing needed is to cast the value you have received from standard input to integer (everything came from stdin is string):

```
- $number = trim(fgets(STDIN));
+ $number = (int)trim(fgets(STDIN));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine for me, except, there are some uninitialized variables, like `$sum` and `$count`.

This is an alternative way.

There are built in functions for this in PHP.

```
<?php
do {
    echo 'Enter a number: ';
    $number = trim(fgets(STDIN));
    if ($number < 1 || !is_numeric($number)) {
        break;
    }
    $numbers[] = $number;
} while (true);


$avg = array_sum($numbers) / count($numbers);
echo("Average : " . $avg);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I will try that. I came across this exercise in my search for interactive php learning site. Found it on programmr site....It's user based site so maybe someone tried to transpone this kind of exercise from Java to php or something like that.